# Modal-like User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a multi tabs winform using a split container. In the right tab I show/hide the user controls using the left tab. Some user controls needs to show a new user control on top of it. The problem is that when the original user control shows the new user controls, I would like that the first user control waits the new one to close (some like ShowDialog in forms), but this screen lock should occour in only one tab.

I tried Threads and many other solutions but none works as I want.

```
{
    var panel = (Panel)this.Parent;
    var searchUserControl = new searchUserControl();
    searchUserControl.Parent = this;
    panel.Controls.Add(searchUserControl);
    this.visible = false; // hides the original form
    // wait
    this.visible = true; // shows the original form again
    var result = searchUserControl.CustomProperty;
}
```

Comment: can't you disable the first user control until done with the 2nd?

Comment: that will not wait for the code

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what you are asking for now.  You want `ShowDialog` like behavior for a `UserControl` but scoped to only one tab page, you still want to be able to change tabs to other pages while the "dialog control" is up though.  You also want to block code execution at the point where the "dialog control" is opened, so that it only runs the next line when the control is closed, presumably returning some kind of "result code", like a dialog would too.  Correct?

Comment: I might be able to rig something like that up using `async`/`await`, but the rest of you code would have to support it (async all the way).

Comment: @BradleyUffner That's exactly it. I'm from web world and and lock with this. I can't block all main form with ShowDialog but I need to open a modal "search" up to a specific container.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.  This is going to be fairly complicated, so it might take  me a bit to get something for you to look at.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I try use async but the elements of the UI must be into the UI Thread (like I can't create a child user control and add it to the main container that holds it).

Comment: I will be glad if you could do something.

Comment: `async`/`await` will keep everything in the UI thread.  There shouldn't be any multi-threading needed.

Comment: This was actually easier than I thought it would be.  I'm working on creating a good answer for you, and uploading source code to Git now.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I found a way using TaskCompletionSource, an event on the close of the 'modal' form and a await. But I would like to see your solution.

Comment: That's exactly what mine uses too.

Comment: Could you link me to the solution you found also?  I'd like to compare.

Comment: Mine is the same yours below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async`/`await` to do this, if you use a few tricks.

The key ingredient is `TaskCompletionSource`.  It represents the "state" of a `Task`, and lets you "complete" it from another point in code, in this case, a button on the "dialog".

Create a `UserControl` to represent your "dialog", give it "ok" and "cancel" buttons, or whatever buttons you need.

The code-behind for the `UserControl` should look something like this:

```
public partial class DialogControl : UserControl
{
    TaskCompletionSource<DialogResult> _tcs;

    public DialogControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Visible = false;
    }

    public Task<DialogResult> ShowModalAsync()
    {
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<DialogResult>();

        this.Visible = true;
        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.BringToFront();
        return _tcs.Task;
    }

    private void btmCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        _tcs.SetResult(DialogResult.Cancel);
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tcs.SetResult(DialogResult.OK);
        this.Visible = false;
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return txtName.Text; }
        set { txtName.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

The `Button` on the main form can use this code to display the "modal control":

```
private async void btnShowDialogControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = new DialogControl();
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(control);

    //Disable your other controls here


    if (await control.ShowModalAsync() == DialogResult.OK) //Execution will pause here until the user closes the "dialog" (task completes), just like a modal dialog.
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Username: {control.UserName}");
    }

    //Re-enable your other controls here.

    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Remove(control);
}
```

Full source code for a working solution can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/BradleyUffner/ModalControl).